# Error using dplyr : object ‘data_frame’ is not exported by 'namespace:vctrs'

Tags: r, dplyr, namespaces, package, vctrs

I have a daily use of tidyverse packages and dplyr in particular.

Today, while running my code which was doing perfectly before

```
dataframe<-dbGetQuery(bdd,"SELECT * FROM scheme.table") %>%
    dplyr::filter(year_end >= 2015 & count_year>=15)
```

I got this error message :
object ‘data_frame’ is not exported by 'namespace:vctrs'

I tried to update the tidyverse,to close my R session and even my windows session but I still have this error each time I'm running a dplyr function.

Can someone help me, I think I don't understand this kinf of error.

PS : here is my R session informations :

```
    sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 16299)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252  LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252    LC_MONETARY=French_France.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=French_France.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] modifiedmk_1.5.0  lubridate_1.7.10  Formula_1.2-4     survival_3.2-7    lattice_0.20-38   sf_0.8-1          RPostgreSQL_0.6-2 DBI_1.0.0        

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] splines_3.6.1      colorspace_1.4-1   vctrs_0.3.1        generics_0.1.0     utf8_1.1.4         rlang_0.4.6        e1071_1.7-3        glue_1.4.1        
 [9] lifecycle_1.0.0    munsell_0.5.0      gtable_0.3.0       class_7.3-15       fansi_0.4.0        Rcpp_1.0.2         KernSmooth_2.23-15 scales_1.0.0      
[17] classInt_0.4-3     grid_3.6.1         tools_3.6.1        magrittr_2.0.1     ellipsis_0.3.0     Matrix_1.2-17      boot_1.3-22        R6_2.4.0          
[25] units_0.6-5        compiler_3.6.1
```

Thanks

Comment: Does it work when you break it down in two statements? `dataframe<-dbGetQuery(bdd,"SELECT * FROM scheme.table")` and `dataframe <- dataframe %>% dplyr::filter(year_end >= 2015 & count_year>=15)`

Comment: Hi Ronak. Not working as well. meanwhile i've updated most of my packages and I got this current message : Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :  namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.6 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.10 is required

Comment: That latter error suggests somehow you have a package that depends on `rlang-0.4.10` but that version is not installed. I think you'll need to update it, but first if you have valuable (hard-to-regenerate data), then you can save it out of the way first. Once you're comfortable, restart R (*without* any `.Rdata` or `.Rprofile` package-loading convenience), update `rlang`, and then try again.

Comment: same problem here but this does not solve it. Instead, I then get the error "Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’: object ‘data_frame’ is not exported by 'namespace:vctrs'"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I had to uninstall and remove all old versions of R and install the latest one. It worked fine after that.

Comment: Same problem here. Reinstalling R seems a bit overkill when a package is updated, does anyone have info about what triggered this?